# How to compare two csv files according to a specific variable (not line by line) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, comparison, difference

I have two csv files I converted from Json file (copy the text in EXCEL and convert to csv),
the format is a bit messy, I want to compare each whole line according to the ID number, but the problem is ID number is in different columns for each row, and I want to print the difference between two lines which have the same ID number.

Here is the data sample (i can't rename each column because each column has different variable values):

CSV_01:

```
age 10   height 150   ID  1001     sex F
age 10   height 150   ID  1001     sex M
ID 1001  height 150   age  12      sex M
age 10   ID  2002     height 151   sex F
age 10   height 150   ID  2002     sex M
```

CSV_02:

```
age 10   height 150   ID  2002     sex F
age 10   height 150   ID  1001     sex M
ID 1001  height 150   age  12      sex M
age 10   ID  1001     height 151   sex F
age 10   height 150   ID  2002     sex M
```

I have almost 1000 rows&500ish columns (and for each row it also contains duplicated same ID) Something like:
age 10   height 150   ID  1001     sex M ... ID  1001 ...

But I assume it doesn't matter, but the variables have different orders, which means ultimately I want to compare **the first 3 rows in CVS_01** with **the 2nd, 3rd,4th row in CSV_02** (because they have the same ID), but this is just an example so it should be different row numbers in my large data set.

Here's what I've tried after importing csv files in Python:

```
resultBool01 = (CSV_01 != CSV_02).stack()  # Create Frame of comparison booleans
resultdiff01 = pd.concat([CSV_01.stack()[resultBool01], CSV_02.stack()[resultBool01]], 
axis=1)
resultdiff01.columns=["output_01", "output_02"]
```

This gave me the difference between each row (i.e: the first row between two files), but this is not what I want, because in the first row they have different ID. I'm stuck for a few days already, not sure if this is the right direction, but it could be more difficult if I compare json or txt files. Can someone help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting your data into a dictionary?

While the csv files are a bit messy, at least they have a clearly defined structure and each fieldname is present before its referenced value.

Whitespaces and other special characters notwithstanding, you could parse each csv line for line first, save each line (or entry) as a dictionary of unique datapoints and append it to a list of dictionaries. Then, you can either operate on it directly, or you can export a properly sorted and aligned csv file for later use.

(I cannot comment yet, so I hope this suffices, otherwise I am happy to help with the actual code, too)

Addendum:

The code might not be perfect for your specific file, but it can serve as a blueprint to develop yours.

Basically, each row as represented in csv (really tsv) format is:

```
fieldname   value   fieldname2   value2   fieldname3   value3
```

and this code will read it in and save the value2 as the value of the key "fieldname2" in a new dictionary, which we then save in a list and later return from the function

```
def filereader(filename):
        _out = []
        with open(filename, 'r',  newline='', encoding='?????') as csvfile:
                csvfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
                for row in csvfile:
                        rowDict = {}
                        rowDict[row[0]] = row[1]
                        rowDict[row[2]] = row[3]
                        rowDict[row[4]] = row[5]
                        _out.append(rowDict)
        return _out
```

Comment: I'm very new to Python, do you mind showing me the codes, thanks.

Comment: Sure. First up: How does the CSV file *actually* look?
Is each value tab-separated from the next?

If so, you could do something like this (see adendum above)

Comment: I ran the function and filereader('run_01.csv'), it gave me an error: TypeError: 'delimiter' is an invalid keyword argument for open(), so each value tab-separated from the next in my csv file because I used 'delimiter' in EXCEL and then convert it to csv, it's complicated now, do you mind writing an example of how th make the csv df into dictionary and compare them?Thank you

Comment: Also this part is not working in my actual dta set. 'rowDict[row[0]] = row[1]
                        rowDict[row[2]] = row[3]
                        rowDict[row[4]] = row[5]'

Comment: Yes, my bad. I put delimiter in the wrong place (fixed). If you succeed reading in the file, print its content to the shell! What does it look like?
Is it a list structure? A string?
I am just going off of assumptions made from your presentation above - the actual file might not fit that assumption.

My code presupposes that the csv file is tab-delimited, where each item is read in as an item in a list, and each row of the file is a new list.

Comment: I read the csv file by using pandas, so they are dataframes, so seems like your codes are not relevant to this situation? Should I convert from dataframe to dictionary.

Comment: I see. I haven't used pandas before. Not sure how dataframes differ in terms of structure from a dictionary. That said, if you need pandas for a specific operation, then I assume that will require the data to be in the dataframe format :( - sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should keep using pandas for this problem, but I'll try to convert it to dictionary first, thank you.